# Working Visa question

Tags: visa, working-visas, interview

I got job offer from Germany but the appointment time from Germany embassy in my country takes 1 year. I have to get in Germany about next 4 months. is there any other alternative solution?

Comment: What is *in my country*? Please [edit] your question. It would probably also good if you edit in a link or text 'proving' the 1 year appointment time so that people can research from there.

Comment: Unanswered duplicate: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/14786/companies-with-visa-sponsored-for-non-european-citizen